# Non compatible application from FreeBSD on Debian?

Tags: debian, compatibility, freebsd

I got an application compiled on FreeBSD (I don't have a source code), when I type `./app` it is running correctly on FreeBSD, but on Debian I get this message in console:

> -bash: ./app: No such file or directory

Of course I'm in the same directory as the 'app' application.

I can not stay on FreeBSD, because I like Debian more. Is it possible to run this application on Debian anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely, but possible. In worst case you should recompile your app on Debian machine.

Also, make sure you have execute flag on ./app file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do, then. There are too much discrepancies in FreeBSD and Debian ABIs.

Answer (score 2):

Both FreeBSD and Linux uses ELF format for executable files, but they have a different ABI.

FreeBSD can execute Linux executable files using linux compatibility layer([aka linuxulator](http://www.leidinger.net/blog/2010/09/28/the-freebsd-linuxulator-explained-for-users/)), but linux(Debian in your case) does not support FreeBSD ABI for ELF.

You need to recompile the application specially for linux.